Terraform : Error: Provider produced inconsistent result after apply with Google cloud
I have a problem with my terraform deployment on Google Cloud.
Here is my terraform file.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "5.24.0"
    }
  }

  backend "local" {
    path = "tf.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = "tayarim-project"
  region  = "europe-west1"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "tayarim_s3" {
  name          = "NAME"
  location      = "EU"
}

resource "google_container_registry" "tayarim_regitstry" {
  location = "EU"
}

I run the command terraform plan
Evrething seems right and when i run terraform apply
I get this error :
Error: Provider produced inconsistent result after apply
│ 
│ When applying changes to google_container_registry.tayarim_regitstry, provider "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google\"]" produced an unexpected new value: Root object was present, but now absent.
│ 
│ This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own issue tracker.
╵

I tried to change provider versions this is not working.

I ran into this issue too and when I enabled verbose logging, I saw that the error happened when terraform was looking for the backing bucket for the container registry. It looks like GCP is migrating people from container registries to artifact registries, so using google_artifact_registry_repository instead fixed the issue.
